# What is the correct syntax for multiple conditions in a Terraform `aws_iam_policy_document` data block

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam

How can this S3 bucket IAM policy, which has *multiple* conditions, be re-written as `aws_iam_policy_document` data block, please?

```json
    "Condition": {
      "StringEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control",
          "aws:SourceAccount": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::my-tf-test-bucket"
      }
    }
```

With the `aws_iam_policy_document` `condition` data block syntax [1](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document#condition):

```
    condition {
      test = "StringEquals"
      values = []
      variable = ""
    }
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [`aws_iam_policy_document`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document) supports multiple [`condition`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document#condition) directives.

The following Terraform configuration should help:

```hcl
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "test" {
  statement {
    effect = "Deny"
    actions = ["backup:*"]
    resources = ["*"]

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      values   = ["bucket-owner-full-control"]
      variable = "s3:x-amz-acl"
    }

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      values   = ["xxxxxxxxxxxx"]
      variable = "aws:SourceAccount"
    }

    condition {
      test     = "ArnLike"
      values   = ["arn:aws:s3:::my-tf-test-bucket"]
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
    }
  }
}

output "policy" {
    value = data.aws_iam_policy_document.test.json
}
```

If we do a terraform plan on that we will get:

```txt
terraform plan
data.aws_iam_policy_document.test: Reading...
data.aws_iam_policy_document.test: Read complete after 0s [id=3933526891]

Changes to Outputs:
  + policy = jsonencode(
        {
          + Statement = [
              + {
                  + Action    = "backup:*"
                  + Condition = {
                      + ArnLike      = {
                          + "aws:SourceArn" = "arn:aws:s3:::my-tf-test-bucket"
                        }
                      + StringEquals = {
                          + "aws:SourceAccount" = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
                          + "s3:x-amz-acl"      = "bucket-owner-full-control"
                        }
                    }
                  + Effect    = "Deny"
                  + Resource  = "*"
                },
            ]
          + Version   = "2012-10-17"
        }
    )
```

Comment: Is this still the case? When I implement the same configuration as given in this answer, terraform warns, "Attribute redefined The argument "condition" was already set at foo/bar/s3.tf. Each argument may only be set once" on `terraform plan`

Comment: Past @UrbanConor should have been paying more attention... 
My problem was with stating `condition`s with an `=` as are how some other attributes are!
State `condition` as `condition {}` not `condition = {...}`!